# bs4 scraping different tags by order of occurence

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape certain tags in order of occurrence. The website html code is:

> ```
> <tbody id="1>
>  <tr class="header">
>  <some other code>
>  <tr class ="unpair">
>   <td class="match">
>  </tr>
> </tbody>
>
> <tbody id=2>
>  <tr class="header">
>  <some other code>
>  <tr class ="unpair">
>   <td class="match">
>  <tr class ="unpair">
>   <td class="match">
>  <tr class ="unpair">
>   <td class="match">
>  </tr>
> </tbody>
> ```

First it should scrape the first class="header" and the first class="matches", then the second one, etc. so I can process the scraped data in pandas by header section.

The code I have so far is :

```
tag_body = soup.find_all("tbody")
headers = tag_body.find_all("tr",class_="header") 
match= tag_body.find_all("td", class_"match)
```

but I could not find an answer to scrape in order of occurrence.

Comment: Could you post the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @ Isma I edited my question

Comment: Could you show what your expected output would be for your example HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of the structure. First you need to find `tbody` tags. Inside these are your `tr` header tags, so use the returned tbody soup to continue searching from that point. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<tbody id="1"><tr class="header"><some other code><tr class ="unpair"><td class="match"></tr></tbody><tbody id="2"><tr class="header"><some other code><tr class ="unpair"><td class="match"><tr class ="unpair"><td class="match"><tr class ="unpair"><td class="match"></tr></tbody>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for tbody in soup.find_all("tbody"):
    tr_header = tbody.find('tr', class_='header')
    print("TR header:", tr_header)
    
    for td_match in tbody.find_all('td', class_='match'):
        print("TD match:", td_match)
```

This would show the `header` and `td` tags in order as follows:

```
TR header: <tr class="header"><some code="" other=""><tr class="unpair"><td class="match"></td></tr></some></tr>
TD match: <td class="match"></td>
TR header: <tr class="header"><some code="" other=""><tr class="unpair"><td class="match"></td></tr><tr class="unpair"><td class="match"></td></tr><tr class="unpair"><td class="match"></td></tr></some></tr>
TD match: <td class="match"></td>
TD match: <td class="match"></td>
TD match: <td class="match"></td>
```

Note: Your HTML is slightly wrong (e.g. `id="1>`)